# How to return verified users on instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

In Instagram Console,

I want to return users who are certified only (people with a badge that attests they are official folks)

Ex. I search 'Rihanna'.
I would like the console to return 'badgalriri' only as this user is certified.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do this with the current api endpoints.